# phonegap: how to close the window

Tags: javascript, cordova

I have a problem... for my app i need to open a page in new window to display the product.

to open the new window I use

```
function testopen(){
    window.open('producttest.html', 'random_string', 'location=no');
    };
```

but when i try in the other window

```
function testcloser(){
    window.close();
    };
```

the app freezes ...

I dont know how to go on ... I've read simmilar topics ... but no solution for me ...

any idea how to work this out?

thanks

Comment: Are you calling window.close from the child window?

Comment: yes I am ... the call is one producttest.html

Comment: dang, thought i might have another way out, but never mind. sorry :(

Comment: no problem man ...  you helped me a lot with the answer ... at least i will not waste hours finding non existing solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, some background :

Cordova uses a single browser window and attaches listeners to it in order to receive messages from its javascript runtime.

I'm not quite sure what would happen if you were to explicitely close this window, but judging from your description it causes the app to hang or crash.

The obvious solution : Do not use `window.open` and `window.close` in Cordova.
Instead, consider using an existing framework like [jQuery mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/) to handle navigation. (though i don't know if this is currently an option for you)

Alternatively, if the `close` call logic came from the other window you could try someting like this :

```
var ref = window.open('somelocation', '_blank', 'location=no');
```

... and to close it, use this.

```
ref.close();
```

Comment: i know this option... but it's usable for me... thanks anyway